# Can the pkgbuild window be made larger?

Tags: pkgbuild

Our pkgbuild installer properly shows the "The installation failed." window when an error occurs. But above that headline there appears the smaller Apple text line

"There were errors with the installation.  You may want to try"

but the rest is cut off by the window edge.  Is there a way to make the pkgbuild window larger so it's not cut off?  Or is there another solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug and there is no solution to this as of now. I have also seen this in some of my installers. I investigated and found that it has nothing to do with pkgbuild. pkgbuild is the tool to build the installers (.pkg files).
When you run these .pkg files, these files get open with an app "`/System/Library/CoreServices/Installer.app`". This is the app that opens the installer window and it has this bug.